# Como verificar se o Eval possui valor nulo?

Tags: asp.net

Estou usando a propriedade Eval para carregar uma campo do `GridView` instanciado de um objeto, o problema é quando o objeto não possui valor , ao em vez de aparecer em branco queria mostrar um traço indicando que não foi encontrado nada.

o código que estou usando é este

```
<%# if(Eval("IdEntradaItem")== "" ||Eval("IdEntradaItem")==null)?" - ": Eval("IdEntradaItem") %>
```

Comment: Você esqueceu de postar o código, poste por favor.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode criar um método público no bean para fazer a validação:

```
public string ValidarItem(object valor)
{
  if (valor == null)
  {
     return "xpto";
  }

  return valor.ToString();
}
```

E no .aspx:

```
<asp:Label ID="label1" Text='<%# ValidarItem(Eval("item")) %>' runat="server"></asp:Label>
```

**EDIT:**

Você também pode fazer assim:

```
<asp:Label ID="label1" Text='<%# Eval("item") ?? "valor_exibir_se_eval_null" %>' runat="server"></asp:Label>
```

Comment: o código que estou usando é este 

<%# if(Eval("IdEntradaItem")== "" ||Eval("IdEntradaItem")==null)?" - ": Eval("IdEntradaItem") %>

Comment: Obrigado a todos que me ajudou há solucionar me problema, mas a solução que o Caique.C propôs ajudou a resolver o problema em questão, é muito obrigado mesmo as pessoa que dedicaram para me ajudar.

Comment: Ainda assim, acho que você pode ter problemas caso seu Eval retorne null... Aconselho a utilização do String.IsNullOrEmpty(Eval("IdEntradaItem").ToString()) como uma solução "mais completa".

Comment: @krispim, se uma resposta lhe ajudou a resolver o problema, sinalize a mesma para que outras pessoas que tiveram a mesma dificuldade possam entender que houve solução.

Comment: @MarllonNasser, não há necessidade da verificação, porque o método Eval retorna um 'string.Empty' se o objeto for nulo.

Answer (score 1):

Utilize dessa forma e veja se funciona:

```
<%# if(Eval("IdEntradaItem").ToString() == string.Empty) ? " - " : Eval("IdEntradaItem").ToString() %>
```